# publish subscriber webservices and route manipulation

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

We have a Websphere Datapower (WDP) infrastructure providing a central endpoint for Soap based web services for logging and many other stuff.

Clients invoke web services using the WDP endpoint for all Web Services and WDP routes the requests to the matching web service based on Web services namespace.

The scenario of the problem is that we have multiple web services with exactly the same wsdl but with different namespaces so a determined client can notify a determined web service or web services depending on some different conditions.

The reason for this is, when new web services are added, we don't need to compile client code to bind the new web service.

I was thinking in manipulating the XML request namespace on client in order WDP know exactly the endpoint web service .

Also I don't want to have any logic on WDP because dependencies reasons.

Is there a better and elegant way of doing this in .net?

Regards